# How to limit the choices of ManyToManyFields to a particular Foreign key only, in Django Model

Tags: python, django, orm

```
class Bank(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

class Branch(models.Model):
    bank = models.ForeignKey(Bank, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class ATM(models.Model):
    bank = models.ForeignKey(Bank, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    branch = models.ManyToManyField(
        Branch)
```

How can I select the multiple branches while adding atm for the particular Bank only? (I know one ATM can't have two branches but I would like to know how can we select the branches for particular bank only?)

Comment: An ATM as you mentioned can’t have two branches, but a branch can have many ATMs. Maybe ATM should be a MtM field on the branch?

Comment: Yes you are right but my model doesn't care if that particular branch location has multiple ATM's. I just want to let people know that that particular branch has ATM(either one or many). But what I am trying to do is if there is an ATM  of particular bank between location of  two branches of same bank then  I want to assign that ATM to both the branches. So when I select one of the bank while adding ATM, the branches selection should only show the branch of that particular bank. But I don't know how beacause it is showing branches of all banks right now.